# How can I edit PNG file rating property value in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-10, png

In Windows 7 and 8 I was able to edit the rating of PNG files by right clicking on that file and going to **Properties**, **Details**, **Rating**.

In Windows 10 this is not available anymore for PNG files, but for other file types like JPEG it is available.

Why is this not available in Windows 10 Enterprise x64?

Comment: It looks like you cannot set rating metadata for PNG files. There is a possible workaround here: http://superuser.com/a/341576/403203 It is a custom program that the user made that can set the **Rating** for any type of file.

Comment: if I will use this custom program, it will save the metadata in a separate file. Right? Which I really don't want!

Comment: Most likely, yes. You will have to ask the creator. Currently there is no native way to do it.

Comment: Relevant: [Does PNG support metadata fields like Author, Camera Model, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8113314/3416774)