# How to use Windows file filtering in thumbnails view

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management, file-filter, file-organization

If you view a folder in details mode and look at the columns header you'll see an arrow next to every one of the properties (name, size, album, artist, etc.). Clicking that arrow gives you a menu listing all the available tags in that given property where you can select the ones you want to filter on that column, then you can filter files even further doing the same in another column, etc.

Here's a screenshot of the file filters.

[image: file filters]

I want to be able to use that feature in other folder views like thumbnails view for example. I'm not sure what is the right approach to achieve this. I thought maybe there could be shortcut for these menus or perhaps a registry tweak to always show the details column header in all the views, but I have no idea how to do that.

After filtering in details view I can then change the folder view to anything else and the filters stay intact so it *does* work in other views, but I have switch to details mode then switch back to thumbnails every time I want to use a filter, so I want to skip this step

Comment: There's no way to accomplish this via the UI, but last time I "played", it was possible with a registry edit. That might not be an option on a workplace computer. Just browsing on my phone right now -- will test and compose an answer when I get home.

Comment: @KeithMiller that'd be great, thank you

Comment: Not forgotten, just delayed, composing answer now...

Comment: good to hear that, i'll be waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:The following is working on my laptop:

> Edition   Windows 10 Home
> Version   22H2
> Installed on  ‎8/‎10/‎2020
> OS build  19045.2486
> Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

Features that are no longer supported can change at any time. I haven't taken the plunge into Windows 11 yes, so no clue on that front.

---

One component of **Explorer** view settings is is a set of flags, [FolderFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-folderflags). the flag that normally supressees the display of column headers is:

> `FWF_NOHEADERINALLVIEWS`
> Value: 0x01000000
> Windows Vista and later. Only show the column header in details view mode.

But even if the flag is cleared in the file template, **Explorer** overrides it when displaying the folder, and headers are only shown in `Details` view. But in **PowerShell**, the flag can be cleared for *active* **Explorer** windows, and the headers will be displayed:

[image]

This **PowerShell** code will turn on column headers in all **Explorer** windows that are open when the command is run:

```
@((New-Object -Com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach({
    $_.Document.FolderFlags = ($_.Document.FolderFlags -band 0xfeffffff)
    $_.Refresh()
})
```

The above code can be copied, pasted into a **POwerShell** console window, and executed for a quick test of its viability; but that's not a great way to execute it for day-to-day use. It seemed to me creating a context menu entry for the *directory background* menu made the most sense. For that, we need a command-line version of the code.

A command line suitable for the `Run` dialog or as the target of a shortcut (and thus also suitable as a context menu command) would be:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command '& {@((New-Object -Com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach({$_.Document.FolderFlags = ($_.Document.FolderFlags -band 0xfeffffff');$_.Refresh()})}'
```

But there's the annoy brief flash of the blue **PowerShell** cosole when the command executes. To get around that, we use `cmd.exe` to launch **Powershell** minimized. Launching **PowerShell** commands from `cmd.exe` presents issues with special characdters and quotation marks that are often solved with refencing `.bat` or `.ps1` files, but we can keep our regsitry command self-contained by using the `-EncodedCommand` PowerShell parameter with a Base64-encoded version of the command. The following code can be copied as a block, pasted into a **PowerShell** cosole and exwecuted to create the context menu entry:

```
$PSCommand      = '@((New-Object -Com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach({ $_.Document.FolderFlags = ($_.Document.FolderFlags -band 0xfeffffff); $_.Refresh()})'
$CommandBytes   = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($PSCommand)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($CommandBytes)

$CommandLine    = 'cmd.exe /c start /min "" PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand ' + $EncodedCommand

$RegKey         = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\ShowColumnHeaders'

[PSCustomObject]@{
    '(Default)' = 'Show Column Headers'
   'Position' = 'Top'
} | Set-ItemProperty -Path (mkdir $RegKey -Force).PSPath

New-Item -Path $RegKey -Name Command -Value $CommandLine | out-null
```

If you prefer, you can create the menu entry by merging a `.reg` file. Here is an export of the reisgtry keys created by the above code. save as a `.reg` file and then merge to create the context menu entry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\ShowColumnHeaders]
@="Show Column Headers"
"Position"="Top"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\ShowColumnHeaders\Command]
@="cmd.exe /c start /min \"\" PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand QAAoACgATgBlAHcALQBPAGIAagBlAGMAdAAgAC0AQwBvAG0AIABzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBhAHAAcABsAGkAYwBhAHQAaQBvAG4AKQAuAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAKAApACkALgBGAG8AcgBFAGEAYwBoACgAewAgACQAXwAuAEQAbwBjAHUAbQBlAG4AdAAuAEYAbwBsAGQAZQByAEYAbABhAGcAcwAgAD0AIAAoACQAXwAuAEQAbwBjAHUAbQBlAG4AdAAuAEYAbwBsAGQAZQByAEYAbABhAGcAcwAgAC0AYgBhAG4AZAAgADAAeABmAGUAZgBmAGYAZgBmAGYAKQA7ACAAJABfAC4AUgBlAGYAcgBlAHMAaAAoACkAfQApAA=="
```

After using either of the above two methods to create the registry keiys, you should see a new item at the top of the background context menu of **Explorer** windows:

[image]

After executing:

[image]

JUst as **Explorer** overrode template settings, the headers will disappear even upon navigating to a subfolder of the current folder. I'm unaware of any way around that -- you simply have to exectue the command again.

Comment: Thank you Keith for the Excellent answer, very clear and informative.

here are my results on W11 22H2 (OS Build 22621.1105),

-using the PowerShell code worked perfectly as expected, the column header shows on all open Tabs
-using the command line in Start>Run, and as shortcut target shows the brief flash of the console but it doesn't actually work (the column header doesn't appear afterwards)
-merging the .reg file worked (but i'm still getting the brief flash of the console window)

Comment: since the headers will disappear even upon navigating, i felt like using a keyboard shortcut for this sort of thing would be a lot quicker, so with the help of AHK i created a hot key for the context menu entry, here it is for anyone interested
https://imgur.com/UQMdF5d

Comment: I wanted to ask you an unrelated question, i hope it doesn't go against any rules to ask this here, but here it goes.. I was curious about these entries in your context menu https://imgur.com/XWsqaxs , especially the "Set Rating".. I'm using desktop.ini files so set rating, comments, Tags and other properties to folders, but your way seems a lot more elegant.. could you please share how are you doing this with the context menu?.. I'm new to SuperUser so please let me know if i should create a separate question for this.

Comment: @Kareem: Hi. Thanks for marking this reply as `Answer`! Could you please throw it an upvote as well? (10 more points! ) I posted the code for the `Add Rating...` context menu entry as an answer to [`This question`](https://superuser.com/a/1741597/881098).

Comment: I already tried to upvote your answer when i marked it but apparently i need 15 reputation points to be able to upvote which i don't have yet (new account).. but the feedback is recorded and should take effect once i have enough points, i also upvoted your "Add Rating" answer on the other post, Thanks for that btw.